# Smart Pointer with explicit constructor gets me an error

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, explicit

I'm trying to build my own Smart Pointer that will allow me to declare it like so:

```
SmartPtr<MyClass> ptr = new MyClass;
```

I want the constructor to be explicit so I made it like so:

```
template<class T>
class SmartPtr
{
public:
    SmartPtr();
    explicit SmartPtr(T* _ptr);
    explicit SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& other);
}
```

However, when I try to declare it as I mentioned on top, I get the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘MyClass*’ to non-scalar type ‘SmartPtr<MyClass>’ requested
```

I know the error is because the copy CTOR has a special syntax with '=' and a conversion CTOR cannot be declared in that method. 
My question is, is there any method to keep the required syntax I mentioned above, and have an explicit CTOR?

Comment: Sorry, I meant copy constructor, I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any method to keep the required syntax I mentioned above, and have an explicit CTOR?

Probably not. That syntax is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and it requires a non-explicit constructor.

Note that the copy constructor does not need to be explicit. If it is explicit then you won't be able to pass `SmartPtr` to a function that accepts it by value.

---

Another way to construct your pointer with minimum syntax overhead is to add a factory function and use it like:

```
template<class T> 
SmartPtr<T> make_ptr(T* p) { 
    return SmartPtr<T>{p}; 
}

auto ptr = make_ptr(new MyClass);
```

Or, something akin to [`std::make_shared<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
auto ptr = make_ptr<MyClass>();
```

Comment: I guess 'no' is also an acceptable answer. I'd prefer to just use the syntax of SmartPtr<MyClass> ptr(new MyClass). Thanks though! if no one else post any positive answer I'll mark yours

Comment: @ofiragranat For copy intialization, the answer is no. `SmartPtr<MyClass> ptr(new MyClass)` is direct intialization, then it's fine.